# Next js images Error: Invalid src prop on `next/image`

Tags: next.js

I'm having the following error in next.js, I'm a beginner and I'm not able to understand the problem, could someone help please?

i can't find what i need to do to fix that, i already tried many things but still with the same error.

Error that i get:

```
Server Error
Error: Invalid src prop (blob:http://localhost:3000/850a9a8b-591d-42f9-8d9d-8bb3e6c7cd94) on `next/image`, hostname "" is not configured under images in your `next.config.js`
See more info: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-image-unconfigured-host
This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Source
src/pages/_document.js (12:8) @ Object.ctx.renderPage

  10 | try {
  11 |   ctx.renderPage = () =>
> 12 |     originalRenderPage({
     |    ^
  13 |       enhanceApp: (App) => (props) =>
  14 |         sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props} />),
  15 |     });
Call Stack
Function.getInitialProps
src/pages/_document.js (17:33)
```

my next.config.js file:

```js
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
const withImages = require('next-images');

const nextConfig = {
  target: 'serverless',
  future: {
    webpack5: true,
  },
  images: {
    domains: ['http://localhost'],
  },
};

module.exports = withPlugins([[withImages]], nextConfig);
```

the component part that i use Image:

```js
{
  releasesData.slice(0, 5).map((release) => (
    <ContainerSpotifyCardsContent>
      <Image
        src={release.image}
        alt={`Pra cego ver: Capa do ${release.tags} ${release.music}`}
        width={90}
        height={90}
        layout="responsive"
      />
      <div className="textContent">
        <span className="songName">{release.music}</span>
        <span className="bandName">{release.artist}</span>
        <span className="styleName">{release.tags}</span>
        <div className="typeContent">
          <span>{release.type}</span>
          <a href={release.links} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
            {SpotifyComponent("#000")}
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ContainerSpotifyCardsContent>
  ));
}
```

my _document.js file:

```js
import React from 'react';
import Document from 'next/document';
import { ServerStyleSheet } from 'styled-components';

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

    try {
      ctx.renderPage = () =>
        originalRenderPage({
          enhanceApp: (App) => (props) =>
            sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props} />),
        });

      const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
      return {
        ...initialProps,
        styles: (
          <>
            {initialProps.styles}
            {sheet.getStyleElement()}
          </>
        ),
      };
    } finally {
      sheet.seal();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to `console.log` the `release.image` value to see if you're getting the expected output ? And also check this, `https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-image-unconfigured-host` ,

Comment: Did you restart Next after updating your config? Also, your domain should not include http - domains: ['localhost']

Answer (score 0):

I have just solved this problem. The next.config.js file was created in the wrong directory so I have just placed it in the main folder of my project.

I hope it helps some people out there because I saw this error on multiple sources without the proper solution...

Answer (score 0):

For **Next.js 13** add image url details at `next.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: '**.example.com',
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

Reference: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image-legacy#configuration-options